# Looking for a folk saying or proverb that reflects "the closer, higher the competition"

Tags: phrase-requests, popular-refrains

I am looking for an American or UK folk saying or proverb that reflects the following idea:

1. the closer are the players, the higher is the competition **or**
2. the more level the playing field, the more intense the competition **or**
3. the more homogeneous the group, the greater the rivalries ...

I think the general idea is clear, if there is no folk saying the fits it then perhaps a Biblical proverb or some classical (Greek or Roman) maxim would be equally helpful. Or even perhaps some short citation that encapsulates the idea in 1, or 2 or 3.

Comment: Can something be "more equal?"

Comment: It reminds me a bit of Animal Farm tbh.

Comment: @Lumberjack: changed "more equal" to "the closer"

Comment: @Lumberjack: Will check Orwell but I don't remember anything like that

Comment: The phrase comes from the end of the tale, around the same time that the pigs decide "4 legs good, 2 legs better."  It goes something like this: "All animals are equal, but some animals are more equal than others".  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any specific saying matching OP's construction and context, but here's...

> *The **more evenly matched** the adversaries are, and the more uncertain the outcome, the **more compelling** is the drama*

...from [*Catholics in the Movies*, Colleen McDannell - 2008](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=329d609gs1wC&pg=PA259&dq=%22the%20more%20evenly%20matched%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cprSU9XtDa2y7AbRgoHYCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20more%20evenly%20matched%20the%22&f=false)

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22universityhood%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22the%20more%20evenly%20matched%20the%22&tbm=bks) are hundreds more instances of *"the more evenly matched the [contestants]"* in Google Books, illustrating many different ways of continuing the "assertion of parallelism".

Comment: It is not what I wanted but searching Google books is a very helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

People will say, "It's going to be a close match" or "It was a close election." You could say two competitors are "neck and neck," to indicate that they're close. You might call your adversary a "worthy opponent." Finally, "stiff competition" indicates a both competition and a tough match.

Comment: Agreed @Qaz  I think [this article](http://www.espncricinfo.com/bangladesh-v-new-zealand-2013-14/content/story/680867.html) manages to use all of the phrases you proposed, as well as another good one, "closely matched."  Unforunately, I fear we may only be answering half of the question.